# Fatal error: Smarty error: unable to write to $compile_dir

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток.
Вот такая ошибка вылазит время от времени на сайте:

> Fatal error: Smarty error: unable to
> write to $compile_dir
> '/var/www/my_rastem/data/www/site.ru/templates_c/default'.
> Be sure $compile_dir is writable by
> the web server user. in
> /var/www/my_rastem/data/www/site.ru/lib/smarty/Smarty.class.php
> on line 1092

Прошу помощи. Как побороть это. Сайт на китайской CMS.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Ну там же написано как. Проверьте корректность пути к файлу и проверьте права на запись в данную директорию. (Китайская Smarty?)

Answer (score 0):

В терминале напишите:

```
chmod -R 777 /var/www/my_rastem/data/www/site.ru/templates_c/
```

Comment: rm -rf / var/www/my_rastem/data/www/site.ru/templates_c/